# Setting tab visibilty to zero crashes app "Null Reference"

Tags: android, visibility, android-tabs

I'm trying two hide two tabs, actually set them to state `GONE` so that they don't take up space in the tab bar either. When I set this it unfortunately crashes my app with a null reference error.

I've used a solution from another question like this:

```
tabLayout.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabLayout.getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But it crashes my app, here is my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_add);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    tabLayout.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tabLayout.getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

How can I set them to `GONE`?

Comment: Hey @Erbez kindly share the stacktrace for the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //To hide the second tab 
((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
//To hide the fourth tab 
((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You have to configure viewpager to make it work correctly as it only hides the tab.

Comment: any idea how to disable scrolling across the tabs?